# Async counter that counts up to 10

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

I am trying to make a counter that counts up to 10. I have used 4 flip flops and I added an AND port so that when the counter reaches 10 it goes back to 0. The problem is that after 10 it goes directly to 16 and then back to 0.
Below is the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Why is your display connected to /Q instead of Q?

Comment: 10 binary is 1010. You must design a logic block that recognizes this pattern and send the reset signal. In your case, U4B is wrong.

Comment: because when connected to Q it counted backwards

Comment: @eri: You deleted your last question on the base 6 and base 8 clock while I was responding to it. It's more polite to post your solution if you've figured it out rather than just delete all the effort put into the comments, etc.

Comment: If it only counts up you only need to AND the 1's, so a two-input AND gate is sufficient. U7A appears to be shorted to the input V1. As @Almost points out your display is connected to inverted outputs so reset is 0xF, also your detection of 0xA is wrong.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I tried connecting the display to Q and not to the inverted outputs, but it counts backwards

Comment: So if you ground the inputs to your display do you get 0 or F?

Comment: If i ground the input displays I get 0

Comment: Oh God! Another *"lets reset all FF's when we see an certain output!"* Please, please add at least a neg-edge clocked FF for the reset!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fixed it. I had to connect the clock of each flip flop to the inverted output Q\ of the previous flip flop. Then I connected the display with the outputs Q and I put as input to the AND gate the Q outputs of the second and the last flip flop.

[image]